# Please separate answer from Ouya question

Tags: discussion, support

I tried out and used [the existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/313618/7146) to [How can I connect an Ouya gamepad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308925/pairing-ouya-controller-with-ubuntu) - it worked and I did my best to improve it a bit.

Since then I've realized that the original poster actually did answer their own question, it's just difficult to read. And that answer is easier.

Please move this bit into an answer, and I can improve it from there:

> Ok.. quick update.. just did the Pair option code 0000 and close.. then i went to pair.. it asked me to enter a pair code.. but after about 2 seconds the window closed and said it was pair successfully.

I did consider just removing that bit and posting it as my own answer, but, y'know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They had already posted this as an answer but it looked like an incorrectly posted update (not an answer) so it was converted into an edit.

I've undeleted the answer. Go wild on it.